# Can UDP packets be really lost when PC connects to itself

Tags: java, udp, voip

Scenarion: VOIP - Sending and Receiving UDP packets at the same time

I have problem when pc connects to itself(for testing purposes). It seems that it looses packets, it doesn't happen though when connecting to the second machine through router wireless. Which is kinda frustrating as I spent 14 hours just to find out that the problem was not in my logic, but rather in a simple case packets never get received.

I have two laptops different benchmarks, both loose packets when connecting to themselves..

```
   sender.start();
    receiver.start();
```

I believe it is something to do with the threading or the nature of NICS. If I remember correctly to either receive or send it changes modes - but because of two threads it can't keep up with them? Am I incorrect?

Why does this happen?

Comment: Provide more information so I can help you!

Comment: I can't really post the code or logic. But literally at the moment removed all the logic and only send and receive methods are called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't mention it in your question, I would advise you to try increasing the size of the UDP receive buffers to see if that makes a difference.

This will also cause less packet loss when running your application over the network (sooner or later packet loss will occur there too).

AFAICT this can be accomplished in Java using the `Socket.setReceiveBufferSize`.

Comment: yeah, the buffer size is the culprit. However I've done that without setReceiveBufferSize. Just introduced artificial delay in the code with while(9999999999) yesterday :-). The problem was when I would accumulate large data structure and then try to send all of them via the loop. I've never really expected java be that fast. I accept yours because you are the closest.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly speaking VOIP is going to loose packets because it is designed that way.

I don't know how many packets you are loosing, but ill try to answer given each senario.

1. Loosing all packets: Probably due to not listening for packets or not connecting to right address
2. Losing a large amount: Probably due to processor speed. If you are encrypting it can be a challenge for the computer to send the data. If it does not encrypt in time it does not send the data. If the data is received late it is dropped.
3. Losing a small amount: This is natural and should happen. VOIP has to be played in order and if a packet comes in after it should have already been played there is nothing you can do with it. This is why it is dropped.

"UDP uses a simple transmission model without implicit handshaking dialogues for providing reliability, ordering, or data integrity. Thus, UDP provides an unreliable service and datagrams may arrive out of order, appear duplicated, or go missing without notice. UDP assumes that error checking and correction is either not necessary or performed in the application, avoiding the overhead of such processing at the network interface level. Time-sensitive applications often use UDP because dropping packets is preferable to waiting for delayed packets, which may not be an option in a real-time system. If error correction facilities are needed at the network interface level, an application may use the Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) or Stream Control Transmission Protocol (SCTP) which are designed for this purpose." - Wiki ([Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol))

Comment: Sometimes a burst of 7-12 under ideal conditions - which is killer for my interleaver. I agree with you, but there are three points: 1. I commented literally everything apart from send and receive methods. It doesn't do any job except assigning packet numbers and sending stubs. 2. When two pcs connected over a network NO packets get lost. 3. I do listen properly, my code throws exception if it can't reach the destination machine.

Answer (score 1):

UDP is a lossy protocol that will not resend packets if they are lost. You are correct in your assumption that packets cannot be lost over the wire when connecting to localhost. However, there is another way to lose packets: the receiver window is full!

When the operating system receive buffer is full because the application lying below cannot process the packets fast enough, packets are lost. The question now is the following: why does this happen on localhost and not on network connections? Here are some guesses:

1. You are working with VOIP. Maybe the codec makes the assumption that network speed will always be the bottleneck? Some protocols allow the receiver to request a higher bitrate if he sees the channel is not saturated yet (no packet loss). How is the system load during your tests?
2. Maybe your threads have a different priority, causing the receiver to never become active.
3. Maybe there is lock contention for some common resource (i.e. access to a single-thread decoding library), causing the sender to be favored.

Try and run sender and receiver from two different JVM's, which will more closely simulate the real situation. Try to introduce lag in the sender by doing a `wait(20ms)` if sending to localhost.